# The database cannot be opened because it is version 782

Tags: база-данных, asp.net, sql-server

Работал с бд, как вдруг выскочила ошибка. Удалил бд, загрузил из бэкапа, запустил, опять вылетела ошибка. Пересоздал бд, после передачи данных опять вылетела ошибка.

> The database...cannot be opened because it is version 782. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported. Could not open new database.... CREATE DATABASE is aborted. An attempt to attach and auto-named database for file...failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

магия...

Answer (score 1):

Бэкап был сделан/база была создана на SQL Server 2014. Вы пытаетесь поднять/приаттачить его на SQL Server 2008. Это невозможно.

Ставьте инстанс 2014-го, и поднимайте бэкап на нем.

Comment: Бэкапилось в течении часа. На одном SQL Server.

Comment: @LEgXr версия SQL Server какая?